# Updating the CSS style of elements based on a radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I have coded 10 radio buttons which work essentially like a star rating. What I want to do is have another 10 button-like circular elements which update based on what radio button is pushed. For example, if the 9th radio button is pushed, I want only the first button-like circular element to get highlighted (change it's css class). Or if the 5th button is pushed, then I want the 5th circular element to update.

I've looked all over for something similar like maybe using a value to display stars but I can't seem to find anything for what I specifically want to do. I would appreciate all help.

Basically my radio buttons look like this (with ten buttons in the actual code but condensed to three buttons on here):

```
  <div class="points">
      <span><input type="radio" name="amount_offered" id="point3" value="3"> 
          <label for="point3">3</label></span>
      <span><input type="radio" name="amount_offered" id="point2" value="2"> 
          <label for="point2">2</label></span>
      <span><input type="radio" name="amount_offered" id="point1" value="1"> 
          <label for="point1">1</label></span>
  </div>
```

The other circular buttons look like this:

```
<div class="pointskeep"> 
    <span><id="point3keep"><label>3</label></span>
    <span><id="point2keep"><label>2</label></span>
    <span><id="point1keep"><label>1</label></span>
</div>
```

My css code looks like:

```
    .points span label {
        border-radius:50%;
        color:black;
        background:white;
    }
    .points span:hover ~ span label,
    .points span:hover label,
    .points span.checked label,
    .points span.checked ~ span label {
        background:goldenrod;
        color:white;
    }

    .pointskeep span label {
        border-radius:50%;
        background:goldenrod;
        color:white;
        }
    .pointskeep span.checked label,
    .pointskeep span.checked ~ span label {
        color:black;
        background:white;
    }
```

My js looks like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        // Check Radio-box
        $(".points input:radio").attr("checked", false);

        $('.points input').click(function () {
            $(".points span").removeClass('checked');
            $(".nopoints span").removeClass('checked');
            $(this).parent().addClass('checked');

        });
```

I've been fiddling a lot with the javascript but I just can't seem to figure out how to update the non-radio elements to their "checked" css style, when the appropriate radio element is clicked. Is there a better approach?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/QPyvnmiHVGdUYGv0rHRs?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This totally works!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').click(function () {
        $('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("checked");
        $('input:checked').parent().addClass("checked");
    });    
});
```

```css
.points span label {
        border-radius:50%;
        color:black;
        background:white;
    }
    .points span:hover ~ span label,
    .points span:hover label,
    .points span.checked label,
    .points span.checked ~ span label {
        background:goldenrod;
        color:white;
    }

    .pointskeep span label {
        border-radius:50%;
        background:goldenrod;
        color:white;
        }
    .pointskeep span.checked label,
    .pointskeep span.checked ~ span label {
        color:black;
        background:white;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="points">
      <span><input type="radio" name="amount_offered" id="point3" value="3"/> 
          <label for="point3">3</label></span>
      <span><input type="radio" name="amount_offered" id="point2" value="2"/> 
          <label for="point2">2</label></span>
      <span><input type="radio" name="amount_offered" id="point1" value="1"/> 
          <label for="point1">1</label></span>
  </div>

<div class="pointskeep"> 
    <span><id="point3keep"><label>3</label></span>
    <span><id="point2keep"><label>2</label></span>
    <span><id="point1keep"><label>1</label></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion! It definitely does work in that it highlights the radio buttons that need to be highlighted but I am looking for a way that the non-button elements can also be highlighted based on what radio button is clicked. Do you have any suggestions on how to do that? Thank you!

Comment: you may achieve it with different attributes like siblings(),child(),etc.

Comment: Can you please explain how I can do that? Should I make the non-radio elements into children? How exactly can I do that? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is how would go about it.

- If a user clicks the button I would get the value of the input
- Get all the non button.
- Compare index with value
- add class accordingly

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').click(function () {
        $('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("checked");
        $('input:checked').parent().addClass("checked");
                  let val = parseInt($('input[name=amount_offered]:checked').val());
        $('.point').each(function(index,element ){
         if(index+1>val)
           $( element ).addClass('checked');
          else
           $( element ).removeClass('checked');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
    .points span label {
        border-radius:50%;
        color:black;
        background:white;
    }
    .points span:hover ~ span label,
    .points span:hover label,
    .points span.checked label,
    .points span.checked ~ span label {
        background:goldenrod;
        color:white;
    }

    .pointskeep .checked{
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background:goldenrod;
      color:white;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="points">
      <span><input type="radio" name="amount_offered" id="point3" value="3"/> 
          <label for="point3">3</label></span>
      <span><input type="radio" name="amount_offered" id="point2" value="2"/> 
          <label for="point2">2</label></span>
      <span><input type="radio" name="amount_offered" id="point1" value="1"/> 
          <label for="point1">1</label></span>
  </div>

<div class="pointskeep"> 
    <span id="point3keep" class="point"><label>3</label></span>
    <span id="point2keep" class="point"><label>2</label></span>
    <span id="point1keep" class="point"><label>1</label></span>
</div>
```